# xmlReadFile failing if proxy enabled

Tags: libxml2

I am using libxml2 library to parse URL. It is working properly in open port environment, but if Proxy is enabled, then xmlReadFile fails. It returns NULL. Please anybody help me ...

Answer (score 2):

I can't test myself, having no proxy. But looking inside the `nanohttp.c` file (belonging to libxml sources) it makes me think that libxml respects **environment variable `http_proxy`**. Try setting this variable before accessing libxml and see if it helps. And don't set `no_proxy` variable as it prevents using the proxy.

Comment: Ganesh, after trying please report if this helps. And if it does, please accept the answer (how? see [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work))

Comment: Hi jarekczek, actually my proxy not allowing to connect...i got following dubug info -  "xmlReadFile" API failed and points out that "xmlNanoHTTPConnectAttempt" [defined in "nanohttp.c"] fails [in fact the "connect(s, addr, addrlen)" call fails].

Comment: Did you provide the credentials, like that: `http_proxy=http://username:password@host:port` ?

Comment: Hi jarekcze, i tried your suggestion, actually my proxy not allowing to connect . i got following debug info. "xmlReadFile" API failed and  points out that "xmlNanoHTTPConnectAttempt" [defined in "nanohttp.c"] fails [in fact the "connect(s, addr, addrlen)" call fails].

Comment: no i didnt gave user name and password...i have given proxy info in the environmental variable.